# Plotting unique dates using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data like `date = '2015-12-12'` and corresponding `y = [0 - 100]` and `date = '2015-03-12'` and `y = [0 - 431]`. How can I plot a bar graph for each unique date against the y column and label the x column with each date value. I also need to slice through the `y` value in  intervals and show them as different colours. How can I achieve this.  Any examples of how to do this. I ideally like to have a graph that looks like
[image: Example graph]

I have tried to get  an example I got so that I can draw the one single bar graph against a single date.  The colours I can do that fine.

```
import numpy as np    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
import datetime
x = '2015-12-12'   
y = [74, 52, 41, 31, 18, 18, 14, 14, 14, 14, 12,0]    
y_values = [y_val for (y_val) in y ]    
ax = plt.subplot(111)    
barWidth=20    
ax.bar(x,y_values, width=barWidth, align='center')    

ax.xaxis_date()
```

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: We won't write full code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to define y values as ranges, a single number for each date (signifying the height) will do. So you'll have your x array, which is date strings, and y array, which is heights.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

x = ['2015-12-12', '2015-12-13', '2015-12-14', '2015-12-15', 
     '2015-12-16', '2015-12-17', '2015-12-18', '2015-12-19']
y = [74, 52, 41, 31, 65, 57, 22, 15]
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
ax.bar(x, y, width=1, align='center')
plt.xticks(rotation=50)
plt.show()
```